# How do i override the views of the "Images" tab of RefineryCMS' admin area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

Is it somehow possible to override the admin interface of RefineryCMS?
Currently i am working on an Online Portfolio based on RefineryCMS + the Portfolio plugin.
I basically want to display add image titles and a description, which are sadly missing.
Luckily i found instructions of how to hack this sort of functionality into the admin area, but i just don't know how to override those view files in the "vendor/plugins" folder.

Here is the link to the instructions i have found:

http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/929d7462cf075189?pli=1

I know this guide is written for Rails 2 and a former version of RefineryCMS, so things might have changed and probably i have to do it every quite differently.

Thanks in advance.

...I really wonder why they still didn't implement those features into the Plugin.

Comment: If I answered your question (below) please mark it as accepted - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to why these are not added into the portfolio extension by default is that the core team behind the portfolio hasn't had a case where they are useful.  We rely on patches to improve or add functionality by people who do come across this need.  There's [an open issue](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-portfolio/issues/39) where nobody has really come up with a solution for yet.

As for the implementation itself; to override the file you are wanting to override you must use the task "bundle exec rake refinery:override" ([using this post as reference](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/msg/44148ecfbfa757a3)) like so:

```
bundle exec rake refinery:override view=portfolio/_main_image
bundle exec rake refinery:override view=portfolio/show
```

This will put the templates in app/views/portfolio/ so that you can modify their contents.

You will also have to change the migration syntax from rails 2 to rails 3 so instead of "script/generate" it's "rails generate".

Because the images extension uses 'attr_accessible' by default for security you will have to use the following code somewhere like config/application.rb:

```
# Make the title and body fields added to Image accessible for mass assignment
config.to_prepare do
  Image.send :attr_accessible, :title
  Image.send :attr_accessible, :body
end
```

Please let me know if you want any of this clarified or if I didn't quite answer your questions satisfactorily and I'll elaborate.

EDIT:

If you want to override the backend view for images, just follow the same process but for the backend views:

```
bundle exec rake refinery:override view=admin/images/_form
```

Now just add the fields in the same format:

```
<div class='field'>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class='field'>
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'wymeditor widest' %>
</div>
```

Because you've already added the attr_accessible code it will save fine.

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

Phil

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was already aware of the possibility of overriding views using the refinery commandline tools, but i just couldn't reach the internal views for the admin panel, where i wanted to add the necessary form fields. For now my solution is therefore to let the admin user put the extra information right into the filename like so: "Title.Oil_on_canvas.30x30.jpg". Then i currently parse this string in the view.

Comment: It would be cool if admin users or at least developers could add extra fields to both the Pages and the Images. I think this would make Refinery a more flexible CMS.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering based on what you linked to. I'll update my answer appropriately. You can override everything (Refinery is a very flexible CMS)